# Java Migration with two data sources

Tags: java, spring, flyway

I need to populate some data in a database managed by flyway with data from another database from an external system that we do not manage by flyway.

We use spring and I have a a DataSource bean available for the external system. Is there a way to inject beans into a flyway java migration in order to do this? Or will I have to create a static variable to access my spring ApplicationContext and just get the bean from there manually?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Java migration for that: http://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/java.html

Comment: I'm not seeing any documentation that refers to having two data sources. I know how to create a basic java migration but I need to know if there is a framework supported way to get a second data source bean from the spring context.

Comment: I don't think so. I think you'd have to make the connection in Java (however appropriate), and do the work there.